# Bio information, such as e-mail and name

Tags: support

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this kind of questions, however, I e-mailed stackexchange support and got no answer back, so here I am.

I deleted my e-mail from my bio (in my account settings). However, everytime I log into my account, I see that it's still there. So, I'd like to know who has access to that information. Everyone? Logged users? Admins only?

Regards,

Comment: See the answer on that duplicate. Only diamond moderators and StackExchange employees can see it.

Answer (score 2):

Only you and moderators can see your email address. It's automatically put back by the system, because that's the email associated with your account. Don't worry, nobody else can see it.